# Split expression using regexp

Tags: regex, split

```
regexp(l,'(\W*+\d{1,3}:\d{1,2})','split')
```

Hello, 
This is my reg exp code.
This is my output

```
46:28 Corner, Switzerland. Conceded by Walter Ayoví. 46:26 Attempt blocked. Stephan Lichtsteiner (Switzerland) left footed shot from outside the box is blocked. Assisted by Granit Xhaka. 45:00][Second Half begins Switzerland 0, Ecuador 1. 45:00 Substitution]
```

I want to add quantifier split

```
46:28 Corner, Switzerland. Conceded by Walter Ayoví. 
46:26 Attempt blocked. Stephan Lichtsteiner (Switzerland) left footed shot from outside the box is blocked. Assisted by Granit Xhaka. 
45:00][Second Half begins Switzerland 0, Ecuador 1. 
45:00 Substitution]
```

to receive such output

How do I add split quantifier in this code such that when a time string (`##:##`) is encountered it starts from a new line.

Comment: The text file that it read has a continuous data.
I wish whenever it reads a time, the data along with time before next time is seen should be in newline. 
I am using regexp for MATLAB.

Comment: I haven't used MATLAB's regexp, but if it supports look-aheads: ` (?=\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` replaced with a newline should match (see http://regex101.com/r/aL5rD4/1)

Comment: regexp(l,'(\W*+\d{1,3}:\d{1,2})')
This is the code, the +sign is must to match. Because sometimes it much match extra time as well. \W* will match the content before it. 
Regexp itself give split within format , but I am having this error 

??? Undefined function or method '_colonobj' for input arguments of
type 'cell'.
 
Above code doesn't generate any result

Comment: You should probably add the MATLAB tag to your post, and edit your post stating that you want to find the equivalent `regex` expression to use in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to split in, but here's `sed`:

```
sed -r s/([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])/\n\1/g
```

Note that this adds a newline immediately before the first line.

Comment: How about the using split in regexp MATLAB?
/g means global implementing of this format?
s/____/ means spliting data within / _ / ?

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi I have no experience in MATLAB. `s/pattern/replacement/flags` is the format for `sed`, with the `g` flag making it global (not just the first occurrence in the line). I'm capturing `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]` (sed doesn't understand `\d`) and substituting every occurrence with a `\n` then the captured match (backreferences are `\1` `\2` `\3` etc in sed)

Comment: Aahh okay, I understand this format now by your elaboration. [0-9] is same thing as\d. I'll try what can I do for MATLAB.

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi yes, `[]` is a character class in regex. The character class `[0-9]` is almost the same as `\d` (I believe `\d` also includes a decimal point, so `\d == [0-9.]`

Comment: Adam,
If I am supposed to only gather the content "(ANYTHING)"
anything within the parenthesis along with parenthesis as well\((.*)\)this would work?

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi to match a literal paren (e.g. `(` or `)`) you'll need to escape it using a backslash. Applying `(\(.*?\))` to `"This is (a parenthetical) reference"` will capture `(a parenthetical)`

Comment: Can you please guide me if I want match the line before matched pattern using regular expression and print that string out assigning a variable.
For every file there will be strictly 2 matches only and I need to assign those to matches to variable to further use it.

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi that sounds like a separate question. Ask a new question for it! :-)